# sql concat query does not working correctly

Tags: sql

SQL concat query does not working correctly

```
UPDATE product
SET    pimg_mid1=concat('.jpg', pimg_mid1) 
WHERE  pid>=21
```

The table column is named by `img_mid1` and currently it contains `xxxxx` type values after 21 rows (21 rows are correct). But required is `xxxxx.JPG`.

All the row except the top 21 are incorrect. These rows should named `xxxxx.JPG` (postfix .JPG)

What would be the right sql query?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you need to reverse the [`concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) data (See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34efa/1)) -- *I am assuming MySQL syntax*:

```
update product
set pimg_mid1=concat(pimg_mid1,'.jpg')
where pid>=21
```